# Can I use spring batch to read and send an entire text file at a time to the ItemProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I have many text files, each with many lines, and all of the lines need to be processed together at the same time by an external process (smooks). How can I read the entire file into a `String` or `List<String>` (since there are line breaks) and send that in full to the `ItemProcessor`?

I have tried to use

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<String> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper());
    return reader;
}
```

but still each row in the file is sent to the `ItemProcessor` separately, which makes sense since that's very well defined in the documentation.  Am I trying to use spring batch in an unintended way?

edit:

I'm trying to work with

```
reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new SimpleRecordSeparatorPolicy(){
    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfRecord(String line){
        if(line.contains("\u001a")){   // EOF character
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
   });
```

but the file does not contain an `EOF` character.  When I manually change the last line to include `"end"` and check for `line.contains("end")` then this works as expected and the entire contents gets sent to `ItemProcessor`.  I think I'm on the right track with some tweaking necessary but if someone has the best practice that'd be fantastic.

Comment: You are on the right track.  A custom RecordSeparatorPolicy is exactly what you need to do for this scenario.  You can read more about them here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/RecordSeparatorPolicy.html

Comment: Thank you for your expertise but I ended up not being able to make this work because there was no way to determine when last line in the file is actually read without modifying the file in some way to place a marker.  Instead, I provided a new implementation of ItemReader and consumed the entire file at once with a BufferedReader.

Comment: Hi @haventchecked, I know it's too late but even I have the similar requirement, if possible can you please guide me on how to achieve with the custom itemReader?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've searched through all of my files and I do not have anything with an itemReader. This problem was from a work related task and I don't have access to that source code any longer. @ShabarinathVolam

Comment: @haventchecked No problem!!, I could able to solve the issue. Thanks for your reply :)